Can a Ger or Goy go into 770 Chabad house?
I am in the process of converting and am currently a Noahide. Can I as a black Noahide wishing to convert or after I convert go into the 770 Chabad house and chill with them? What do they do there?

770 Eastern Parkway is classified as an Orthodox synagogue.  Anybody can visit, properly dressed.

It's also a yeshiva. "What they do" varies by location and time of day. But yes, people of all stripes can and do visit.

Black Noahide. Kol hakavod. I'll bet they'll be excited to see you. Isaiah 56:7
“for My house shall be called a house of prayer for all nations.” - Applies to all synagogues.
